# how to change EditTexts with same width in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

In my layout there are many EditTexts, i want to make same width for all.  I tried with below code and the EditTexts showing different width. how can i solve this problem.  My layout as follows

thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Basic Settings"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Home ID"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homeid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"                    
                android:text="Home Name"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:singleLine="true"/>                 

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"                    
                android:text="Home Password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homepw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword|number"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/white"                    
                android:text="Home Re-password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homerepw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword|number"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="IP Settings"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

screen shot of application

[image]

Comment: Just use `android:layout_width="0dip"` for both TextView and EditText inside LinearLayouts.. Thats it.. Simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take effect `android:layout_weight="1"` attributes for width you have to set `android:layout_width="0dip"` for both ChildViews (TextView and EditText)

Something like:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dip" // this line need to be change
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Home ID"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homeid"
                android:layout_width="0dip" // this line need to be change
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: one more doubt, how can i change an EditText accepts only numbers as password

Comment: Means?? I don't get you?? For numeric keyboard you can use `android:inputType="phone"`. And for get only digit input you have to put filter for that..

Answer (score 2):

[image]

you have to assign same width for all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
             android:textColor="#000000"      
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Basic Settings"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                 android:textColor="#000000"      
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Home ID"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homeid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="5"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                   android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textColor="#000000"                         
                android:text="Home Name"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="12"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:singleLine="true"/>                 

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                 android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="#000000"                        
                android:text="Home Password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homepw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textPassword|number"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
               android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="#000000"                    
                android:text="Home Re-password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/setup_homerepw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword|number"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
         android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="IP Settings"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: though its a solution, giving fixed size to widgets should be avoided, as it can create problems for different resolutions.